# Ordering points when making line in QGIS Virtual Layer

Tags: qgis, sql, polyline-creation, vertices, virtual-layer

I've got a QGIS point geometry layer with four point features and a numeric field `sequence`. I want to create a virtual layer joining these points into a line geometry layer (which will have one feature) in order of increasing `sequence`.

I can make a virtual layer with a line feature from the points using:

```sql
select makeline(geometry) as geom
from FourPoints
```

and I get three sides of a square, joined in the order I created them (temporary scratch layer, points). But I can't see how to order it by attribute. Trying:

```sql
select makeline(geometry) as geom
from FourPoints
order by sequence
```

makes no difference. Do I need to do a subselect from `FourPoints` first, ordered by `sequence`, and then `makeline(geometry)` from that? How? My SQL-fu is weak.

Making new real layers isn't an option, since I will be editing the point layer and I'd like the line layer to update magically, also I have more than one "sequence" column and I'd like to have multiple virtual layers, for different sequence columns.

If easier, I could renumber the sequence variable to be strictly incrementing by 1 every time, so then its a case of joining the point with sequence value `i` to that with sequence value `i+1`. Not sure if that could then be done with a geometry generator within a point layer...

Comment: My suggestion is to subselect from FourPoints first, ordered by sequence, and then `makeline(geometry)` from that using the `WITH` clause.

Comment: Yes but subselects are a bit beyond my sql skills at the moment. I'll see what I can do...

Comment: slightly off topic, but with PostGIS we could do `select st_makeline(geom ORDER BY id) from src;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You resolved your problem already but here is a full test case with data. Save the GeoJSON as "seq.json" and run the ogrinfo commands for testing.

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "seq1":1, "seq2":1 }, "geometry": {"type":"Point","coordinates":[-10,8]} },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "seq1":2, "seq2":2 }, "geometry": {"type":"Point","coordinates":[-7,0.0]} },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "seq1":3, "seq2":4 }, "geometry": {"type":"Point","coordinates":[0.0,0.0]} },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "seq1":4, "seq2":3 }, "geometry": {"type":"Point","coordinates":[3,8]} }
]
}

ogrinfo -dialect sqlite -sql "select makeline(geometry) from (select geometry from seq order by seq1)" seq.json
 LINESTRING (-10 8,-7 0,0 0,3 8)

ogrinfo -dialect sqlite -sql "select makeline(geometry) from (select geometry from seq order by seq2)" seq.json
 LINESTRING (-10 8,-7 0,3 8,0 0)
```

Comment: Nice, and nice testing framework via command line - this SQL does still work in QGIS virtual layers in case anyone wasn't sure.

Answer (score 4):

This SQL subselect seems to work:

```
select makeline(geometry) as geom from (select * from FourPoints order by sequence)
```